# Order of punctuation marks vs letters

Tags: c#, string

In C#, it is well known that `".".CompareTo("A") == -1` .

My question is: is there a punctuation mark x such that `x.CompareTo("A") == 1` (strangely I can't find the answer anywhere)

or in other terms, what is the complete default order for strings in C# ?

I know I can define Comparers and Comparisons, but I am asking this question because I am using a class that I cannot modify and that performs a default alphabetical sort on a List of strings.

My problem is that I need to put some dummy values at the end of the list and I would rather have something like:

```
"value 1"
"value 2"
"_"
"_"
"_"
```

than

```
"value 1"
"value 2"
"zzz"
"zzz"
"zzz"
```

EDIT:

This is not great but I will use (char)738

Comment: It is not “well-known” that `"." < "A"`. That code doesn't compile. Did you mean `'.' < 'A'`?

Comment: @svick, sorry I meant ".".CompareTo("A") == -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use character with code you like (i.e. character `'\uffcc'` or string `"\uffcc"`) as sentinel as long as you don't need to make it printable.

Character comparison uses Unicode (UTF-16) character codes. So look at Unicode table to find some like:

'A' < '{' or 'A' < '¡'.

String comparison: there are no "<" and ">" operators in String class. You need to use [Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx) method. Usually you use [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) class to pick what type of comparison you want case sensitive, culture aware or just by Unicode values.

Unicode type of characters impact default comparison used by CompareTo (when not using compare ordinal). Character with category "OtherLetter" is greater than character with category "OtherSymbol" or "OtherPunctuation" ([Char.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360z2b3k.aspx)). See [CompareOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx).StringSort for details.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I guess I will just output all the characters and check if they're bigger than A...

Comment: Interesting `"\uFFCC".CompareTo("A") == 1` but something like `"\uFFFC"` is -1.

Comment: It's very strange yes, everything that remotely looks like a punctuation mark shows as smaller than any character...

Answer (score 2):

Characters in C# are UTF-16 (16-bit characters).

The following ASCII (i.e. found on a standard US keyboard) non-letter characters come after A:

[ \ ] ^ _ `

The following come after A as well as after lower-case a:

~ { | }

There are also a number of other special characters above the ASCII range

See

http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374081.aspx

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it seems C# is not using utf8. I'll try Unicode

Comment: C# uses utf-16.  You can convert a string to UTF-8 using an encoder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I tried "~" and it doesn't work. I don't think the CompareTo function is based on utf 16 codes.

Answer (score 0):

The sort order of characters is just based on their ASCII values.

[Example ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

So yes, there are a lot of characters that are "higher" than A.

Comment: Actually, according to the Unicode values.  ASCII is a subset of Unicode.