# string(";P") is bigger or string("-_-") is bigger?

Tags: c#, c++, char

I found very confusing when sorting a text file. Different algorithm/application produces different result, for example, on comparing two string  `str1=";P"` and `str2="-_-"`

Just for your reference here gave the ASCII for each char in those string:

```
char(';') = 59;   char('P') = 80;
char('-') = 45;   char('_') = 95;
```

So I've tried different methods to determine which string is bigger, here is my result:

1. In Microsoft Office Excel **Sorting** command:

   ";P" < "-_-"
2. C++ std::string::compare(string &str2), i.e. `str1.compare(str2)`

   ";P" > "-_-"
3. C# string.CompareTo(), i.e. `str1.CompareTo(str2)`

   ";P" < "-_-"
4. C# string.CompareOrdinal(), i.e. `CompareOrdinal(w1, w2)`

   ";P" > "-_-"

As shown, the result varied! Actually my intuitive result should equal to Method 2 and 4, since the ASCII(';') = 59 which is larger than ASCII('-') = 45 .

So I have no idea why Excel and C# string.CompareTo() gives a opposite answer. Noted that in C# the second comparison function named `string.CompareOrdinal()`. Does this imply that the default C# `string.CompareTo()` function is not "Ordinal" ?

Could anyone explain this inconsistency?

**And could anyone explain in CultureInfo = {en-US}, why it tells ;P > -_- ?** what's the underlying motivation or principle? And I have ever heard about different double multiplication in different cultureInfo. It's rather a cultural shock..!

Comment: Look at the second parameter in `CompareTo()`.

Comment: Two other options, beside ordering based on the ordinal values, are length comparisions (unlikely), or lexicographical comparisions, which is most likely the case for your "unexpected" results. Also, "bigger" is really the wrong word here. The "bigger" string would be "-_-", since it's 3 characters as opposed to ";P" with 2 characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of punctuation marks vs letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475535/order-of-punctuation-marks-vs-letters). Check out links from my answer there - especially CompareOptions.StringSort one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. ?
2. [`std::string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/): "the result of a character comparison depends only on its character code".  It's simply ordinal.
3. [`String.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx): "performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture".  So,this not ordinal, since typical users don't expect things to be sorted like that.
4. [`String::CompareOrdinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af26w0wa.aspx): Per the name, "performs a case-sensitive comparison using ordinal sort rules".

EDIT: [`CompareOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx) has a hint: "For example, the hyphen ("-") might have a very small weight assigned to it so that "coop" and "co-op" appear next to each other in a sorted list."

Comment: My CurrentCultrueInfo = {en-US}; I am wondering why in {en-US} cultrue  ';' can be smaller than '-'? what's the underlying motivation? Sorry i can only found the definition of CultureInfo in .Net but don't know why different culture should define different comparison method on characters.

Comment: Added 1. to make sure the numbers were same as in the question. Unfortunately SO markup does not respect the actual numbers you use in building the list.

Comment: Yes if anyone can explain why Excel (Office 2003) produce such result as well?

Comment: @JXITC: at a guess, symbols are considered to be before letters in general but the hyphen is used (especially in US English) to make things like compound adjectives rather than for significant structure, so is considered to be of lower importance than something like a semi-colon that is very structural.

Comment: @Tommy Thank you! That's a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Excel 2003 (and earlier) does a sort ignoring hyphens and apostrophes, so your sort really compares `;` to `_`, which gives the result that you have. Here's a [Microsoft Support link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/212144) about it. Pretty sparse, but enough to get the point across.

Comment: Oops! Haha I have never thought about that they would ignore hyphens. Interesting!