# How does .NET sort special characters?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

Why does .NET sort the characters '+' and '^' in a different order than they appear in [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) or the way SQL sorts them.

In [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) '+' has value of 42 and '^' has value of 94 but if you run code like this:

```
var list = new List<string> { "+", "^", "!" };
list.Sort();
```

The list will contain values in the following order:

{ "!", "^", "+" }

LINQ sort generates the same result.  Can someone tell me what kind of sort .NET does?

Comment: You aren't sorting the characters, you are sorting strings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

.NET doesn't use ASCII, it uses Unicode. When you perform a string sort, .NET (by default) uses the current culture's rules for sorting. In this case, those rules indicate that "^" comes before "+". You can  get the result you expect by using the "ordinal" string comparer:

```
var list = new List<string> { "+", "^", "!" };
list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal); // Order is "!", "+", "^"
```

Comment: +1. Some links to sorting rules can be found in my answer to similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475535/order-of-punctuation-marks-vs-letters/9475570#9475570

Answer (score 2):

This is defined by the current culture set, defined in the [CompareInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.compareinfo.aspx) property.  Each culture has culture-specific sorting rules for strings.